# Do scriptures talk about some men not having nipples?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, men

In his book Jaya, Devdutt Patanaik mentions the following:

[image]

<sub>(From: Jaya: An Illustrated Retelling of the Mahabharata By Devdutt Pattanaik)</sub>

So my questions are:

1. Is there any scriptural references to support this claim?
2. Who are all the men who didn't have nipples and why didn't they have them?

Comment: Information : I have heard from someone that in one `kalp` of bramha only one purna purusha (100% male) take birth which is Arjun. And mostly he takes birth during the Lord Vishnu takes an avatara so it is to be called as `Nar-Narayana` pair.

Comment: The biological reason is that the default build for a human body is female. All male anatomical parts are female parts that have been either suppressed or enhanced during the fetal stage by hormones. Your question is about myth, not Hinduism.

Comment: Can you explain me what has Hinduism have to do with this? I think people from other religion has the same thing ....

Comment: @Mr.Alien: As I SPECIFIED in my question that 
**I have heard that there are Five male only who didn't have nipples and that's why they were called Purna Purusha. (I could recall ony 2 names from them, Those are Arjuna from Mahabharata and another is King Harish Chandra (A.K.A Satyawadi Raja Harishchandra)).**
and this all PURNA PURUSHA  are from Hindu religion. So can you tell me why it is not related to Hinduism.? and only If don't you know, Hinduism is world's first religion from which all other religions came. So It is possible that "people from other religion has the same thing"

Comment: @Pritam Sorry but we are no more discussing over HEARD things, if you can than please share a link where you read that or a reference of some book or something similar to support your question.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I found a reference to it in Devdutt Pattanaik's book Jaya: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gzN2_fu0mIYC&lpg=PA126&dq=purna%20purusha%20nipples&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q&f=false I'm not sure whether it has any basis in Hindu scripture though.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Now reference has been added to the question. Do you still doubt about question?

Comment: Who is Pattanik Devadutt some spiritual Rishi or God? What a joke he says. He himself has no proof for his this claim . And nipples are not feminine or masculine. Also , nipples are erogenous parts in both male and female . I was truly laughing at this claim of Pattanik.  